# c# windows form: How to match backgroundimage size to form size

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image

I am trying to match form size to the form background image size. The code:

```
var newImage = PB_DEPTH.Image;
var newForm = new Form();

newForm.BackgroundImage = newImage;
newForm.Width = this.depthFrameDescription.Width;
newForm.Height = this.depthFrameDescription.Height;
newForm.Show();
```

Problem is new form still crops part of the image. I imagine that this is due to the top menu strip containing the close, minimize, maximize icons.

Is there any way to get the size of that strip instead of applying constant offset values?

Or better yet a way to properly resize a form to match backgroundimage dimensions.

Comment: `ClientRectangle` of the form is the size of form interior. Difference with `Bounds` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `newForm.ClientSize` to the size of your background image.